# requireJS optimization: undefined is not a function

Tags: requirejs

Without using optimization, application is working fine. But with optimization (minifying JS), the minified file throws "undefined is not a function" when loading homepage.

The issue is : in the main config file, i am using like below which creates loading problem in the line `-- new controller() - undefined`.

```
domReady(function() {

        if (domReady) {
    calendar.controller = new controller();
    if (Backbone) {
                Backbone.history.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

My build.js is below:

```
({
    'baseUrl': './',
    'dir': '../build/js',
    'paths': {
        'jquery': 'require-jquery',
        'underscore': 'lib/lodash.min',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone-min',
        'mustache': 'lib/mustache',
        'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap.min',
        'fullcalendar': 'lib/fullcalendar.min',
        'controller': 'calendar/controllers/home_controller',
        'jqueryui':'lib/jquery-ui.min',
        'moment':'lib/moment.min',
        'customscroll':'lib/jquery.mCustomScrollbar',
        'mousewheel':'lib/jquery.mousewheel.min',
        'validate':'lib/jquery.validate.min',
        'datatable':'lib/jquery.dataTables.min',
        'blockUi':'lib/jquery.blockUI',
        'fileupload':'lib/fileuploader'
    },
    'shim': {
        'underscore': {
            'exports': '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            'deps': ['jquery','underscore'],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'jQuery.fn.alert'
        },
        'fullcalendar': {
            'deps': ['jquery']            
        },
        'jqueryui': {
            'deps': ['jquery']            
        },
        'customscroll': {
            'deps': ['jquery']            
        },
        'mousewheel': {
            'deps': ['jquery']            
        },
        'validate': {
            'deps': ['jquery']            
        },
        'datatable': {
            'deps': ['jquery']            
        },
        'fileupload': {
            'deps': ['jquery','jqueryui']            
        },
        'blockUi': {
            'deps': ['jquery']            
        },
        'controller': {
            'deps': ['backbone','fullcalendar','jqueryui','moment','customscroll','mousewheel','validate','datatable','blockUi','fileupload']
        }       

    },
    'locale': 'en-us',
    'optimize': 'uglify',
    'inlineText': true,
    'modules': [

        {
            'name': 'calendar/controllers/home_controller',
            'exclude': ['jquery']

        }

    ]
})
```

RequireJS version: 2.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the optimizer is not finding your shim config. You will need to specify it using the mainConfigFile build option.

```
mainConfigFile: 'path/to/main.js'
```

More information on this config option can be found in [require.js API doc - Main config file](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#mainConfigFile):

> You should use the mainConfigFile build option to specify the file
>   where to find the shim config. Otherwise the optimizer will not know
>   of the shim config. The other option is to duplicate the shim config
>   in the build profile.

As you already have it in your build profile, try the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, I tried as mentioned but i got an error: 

Error: The config in mainConfigFile <<PATH TO MAIN.JS>> cannot be used because it cannot be evaluated correctly while running in the optimizer. Try only using a config that is also valid JSON, or do not use mainConfigFile and instead copy the config values needed into a build file or command line arguments given to the optimizer.
    at Function.build.createConfig (/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:14836:23). 

Also i copied the shim part alone from main.js into the build file and still facing the same issue.

Comment: I don't see in your shim where are you exporting object calendar? Where is it defined?

Comment: Yes, yes yes! Mine... `mainConfigFile: '../app.js'`