# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when using require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm new to require.js so I may not be using it correctly, but as far as I know, I can't find what's causing the error.

Structure

```
index.html
Scripts\
  - jquery-2.1.1.min.js
  - require.js
  \app
    - main.js
  \lib
    - work-requests.js
    - controller-base.js
    - util.js
```

index.html

```
<script src="Scripts/require.js" data-main="Scripts/app/main"></script>
```

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'Scripts/lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../jquery-2.1.1.min',
    },
});
requirejs(['jquery', 'util', 'work-requests'], function ($, util, work_requests) {
    $(function () {
    var foo = new work_requests.get_all(); // <-- error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
});
```

work-requests.js

```
define(['controller-base'], function (controller_base) {
    return function () {
        var that = controller_base('work-requests')

        return that;
    }
});
```

controller-base.js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    return function (controller_name) {
        var that = {};
        that.controller = controller_name;

        that.get_all = function () {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: _api_root + '/' + that.controller,
            });
        };
        return that;
    };
});
```

util.js

```
define({
  foo: function(data){},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your require.js setup is completely fine.  Did you try changing

```
var foo = new work_requests.get_all();
```

to

```
var foo = new work_requests();
var bar = foo.get_all();
```

?

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate.

You're looking for `mainConfigFile: 'path/to/main.js'`
[requireJS optimization: undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233372/requirejs-optimization-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Apparently this is a dupe. Where is the other question? I can't find it now.