# RequireJS optimizer fails to load external facebook js correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, requirejs

My file structure looks like this. Everything is inside the js folder.

```
-js  
  --config.js  
  -app  
    --app.fb.js  
    --main.js  
  -lib  
    --jquery-1.9.0.js
    --require.js  
  -tools  
    --r.js  
    --build.js
```

I've created a config file as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/requirejs

config.js

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'facebook' : { exports: 'FB' }
  },
  paths: {
      'jquery': '../lib/jquery-1.9.0',  
      'facebook': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all'
  }
});
```

app.fb.js

```
define(['facebook'], function(){
    console.log("loaded fb");
});
```

build.js

```
({
    baseUrl: "../app",
    mainConfigFile: "../config.js",
    name: "main",
    out: "../core.js",
    paths: {
      'facebook': 'empty:'
    }
})
```

main.js

```
require(["jquery", "app.fb"], function($, appfb){
    // Log the callback parameter.
    console.log( "$.fn.jquery:", $.fn.jquery );
});
```

finally I call the optimized file(core.js) here

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/core" src="js/lib/require-2.1.15.js"></script>
```

The optimizer appears to run correctly but when I load the page I expect the Facebook module to load in from the CDN. Instead I get
GET http://example.com/js/facebook.js  require-2.1.15.js:1901
Uncaught Error: Script error for: facebook

I've spent ages on this and can't figure out the problem! 
Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, for some reason this only worked when I moved the config.js contents into main.js.

This looks like:

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'facebook' : { exports: 'FB' }
  },
  paths: {
       'jquery': '../lib/jquery-1.9.0',  
       'facebook': '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all'
   }
 });
require(["jquery", "app.fb"], function($, appfb){
    // Log the callback parameter.
     console.log( "$.fn.jquery:", $.fn.jquery );
 });
```

In build.js, change

```
mainConfigFile: "../app/config.js",
```

to

```
mainConfigFile: "../app/main.js",
```

r.js optimiser runs correctly!

Comment: Similar note here about the importance of `mainConfigFile` ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233372/requirejs-optimization-undefined-is-not-a-function